# Counting ways of breaking up a string of digits into numbers under 26

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a string of digits, I wish to find the number of ways of breaking up the string into individual numbers so that each number is under 26.

For example, "8888888" can only be broken up as "8 8 8 8 8 8 8". Whereas "1234567" can be broken up as "1 2 3 4 5 6 7", "12 3 4 5 6 7" and "1 23 4 5 6 7".

I'd like both a recurrence relation for the solution, and some code that uses dynamic programming.

This is what I've got so far. It only covers the base cases which are a empty string should return 1 a string of one digit should return 1 and a string of all numbers larger than 2 should return 1.

```
int countPerms(vector<int> number,  int currentPermCount)
{
    vector< vector<int> > permsOfNumber;
    vector<int> working;
    int totalPerms=0, size=number.size();
    bool areAllOverTwo=true, forLoop = true;

    if (number.size() <=1)
    { 
        //TODO: print out permetations
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < number.size()-1; i++) //minus one here because we dont care what the last digit is if all of them before it are over 2 then there is only one way to decode them
    {
        if (number.at(i) <= 2)
        {
            areAllOverTwo = false;
        }
    }
    if (areAllOverTwo) //if all the nubmers are over 2 then there is only one possable combination 3456676546 has only one combination.
    {
        permsOfNumber.push_back(number);
        //TODO: write function to print out the permetions
        return 1;
    }
    do
    {
        //TODO find all the peremtions here
    } while (forLoop);

    return totalPerms;
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate why '88888888' returns 1 and '12345678' returns 3?

Comment: I don't understand how you get from 88888888 to 1 and from 12345678 to 3. BTW: You have "perms", "permetations", "permetions" and "peremtions" -- if you can't find the proper spelling of what you want, you will also have problems finding any suggestions online.

Comment: @billz sure,for '88888888' it returns 1 because the only number under 26 is 8 so the only way to have the string of '88888888' is that string. as for the '12345678' the numbers would come out to be '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8', '12 3 4 5 6 7 8' and '1 23 4 5 6 7 8'

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yes I know I have spelling issues in the code, however I do not believe that I am calling this the right name so I am not sure that it matters much :-/

Comment: So, you want to find the number of different ways to split the string into numbers (pairs or single digits) less than 26. Now, for that you can always use different substrings that are each built upon each other, which is why linear programming could come handy. E.g. 1234 can be split into 1 and the different splits of 234 or into 12 and the different splits of 34.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yes that is what I want to find. I am just having issues with wrapping my head around how to make all the different splits happen. I know I need to loop over the whole string but I am not sure how to know when I am done, so i can break out of the loop.

Comment: probably you mean "counting digits under 26" instead of "finding all numbers under 26"

Comment: Can number begins with `0` (so `101` can be ,`1 0 1`, `10 1` or `1 01`) ?

Comment: @Jarod42 yes it can begin with a 0 but 0 must be counted on its own. (so "101" can only ever be '1 0 1' also "010" can only ever be '0 1 0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you either don't have zeros, or you disallow numbers with leading zeros), the recurrence relations are:

```
N(1aS) = N(S) + N(aS)
N(2aS) = N(S) + N(aS) if a < 6.
N(a) = 1
N(aS) = N(S) otherwise
```

Here, `a` refers to a single digit, and `S` to a number. The first line of the recurrence relation says that if your string starts with a `1`, then you can either have it on its own, or join it with the next digit. The second line says that if you start with a `2` you can either have it on its own, or join it with the next digit assuming that gives a number less than 26. The third line is the termination condition: when you're down to 1 digit, the result is 1. The final line says if you haven't been able to match one of the previous rules, then the first digit can't be joined to the second, so it must stand on its own.

The recurrence relations can be implemented fairly directly as an iterative dynamic programming solution. Here's code in Python, but it's easy to translate into other languages.

```
def N(S):
    a1, a2 = 1, 1
    for i in xrange(len(S) - 2, -1, -1):
        if S[i] == '1' or S[i] == '2' and S[i+1] < '6':
            a1, a2 = a1 + a2, a1
        else:
            a1, a2 = a1, a1
    return a1

print N('88888888')
print N('12345678')
```

Output:

```
1
3
```

An interesting observation is that `N('1' * n)` is the n+1'st fibonacci number:

```
for i in xrange(1, 20):
    print i, N('1' * i)
```

Output:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 5
5 8
6 13
7 21
8 34
9 55
```

Comment: How would this change if we were to allow 0's which I have to do?

Comment: @Lupus It depends: what should the result for "5005" be? If the only legal way to write it is "5 0 0 5" then no change is necessary. If "5 00 5", "5 0 05" and "5 005" are also legal, then you need a new case that treats '0' like '1' in the recurrence relations.

Comment: (Actually, my previous edit is wrong: `N(0S) = 2N(S)` is the rule you'd need to add if leading zeros are allowed).

Comment: Ahh ok, the only valid result for "5005" would be "5 0 0 5" 
can you tell me if "for (int i = number.size()-2; i >-1; i--)" is a valid translation from your xrange loop into c++; I am trying to implement this but I am getting strange numbers on my end.

Comment: why would N(0S) = 2N(S)? I dont see how adding one 0 in the string could double the ouputs if 0 has to be counted separately.

Comment: @Lupus This is going to be my last comment: I feel like I've helped you enough already. `N(0S) = 2N(S)` holds if leading zeros are allowed, not if 0 has to be counted separately. Your loop looks correct, but I can't debug your code for you.

Comment: I would upvote if i could, but I dont have enough rep to do so. While I believe right now that this is the answer, I want to wait a bit before I accept it just to give some more people time to take a look at it. Should no one else offer up any answers that are better I will make sure to mark this one.

Comment: There's a mention in wikipedia about the Fibonacci relationship (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number): *"These numbers also give the solution to certain enumerative problems. The most common such problem is that of counting the number of compositions of 1s and 2s that sum to a given total n: there are Fn+1 ways to do this."*

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, there are only 25 possibilities.  My first crack at this would be to initialize an array of 25 ints all to zero and when I find a number less than 25, set that index to 1.  Then I would count up all the 1's in the array when I was finished looking at the string.

What do you mean by recurrence?  If you're looking for a recursive function, you would need to find a good way to break the string of numbers down recursively.  I'm not sure that's the best approach here.  I would just go through digit by digit and as you said if the digit is 2 or less, then store it and test appending the next digit... i.e. 10*digit + next.  I hope that helped!  Good luck.

Comment: by recurrence I mean something like the formula for finding Fibonacci numbers were F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2). My function shouldn't be recursive however.

Comment: This idea is good however it will only give me one of the possible strings. and if I am following the logic correctly for the string 12121212 your array would look like this [0,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0] or am I just botching up what you are thinking?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think about it is that, after the initial single digit possibility, for every sequence of contiguous possible pairs of digits (e.g., 111 or 12223) of length `n` we multiply the result by:

```
1 + sum, i=1 to floor (n/2), of (n-i) choose i
```

For example, with a sequence of 11111, we can have

```
i=1, 1 1 1 11 => 5 - 1 = 4 choose 1 (possibilities with one pair)
i=2, 1 11 11 => 5 - 2 = 3 choose 2 (possibilities with two pairs)
```

This seems directly related to Wikipedia's description of Fibonacci numbers' "Use in Mathematics," for example, in counting *"the number of compositions of 1s and 2s that sum to a given total n"* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Using the combinatorial method (or other fast Fibonacci's) could be suitable for strings with very long sequences.